# Reading TxPool using GO

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, txpool

Hello I am trying to learn Go and have not been able to figure out how to get pending transactions. I was reading the following link but I am not sure what I should be importing:

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-txpool

Any help or suggestions is appreciated, thanks.